# Cassandra-Hector Single-Node Cluster HUnavailableException: : May not be enough replicas present to handle consistency level

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

i'm trying to create a cassandra database using a single node cluster(i think) but no matter whatever value i set the replication factor i keep getting this error:

*me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HUnavailableException: : May not be enough replicas present to handle consistency level.*

Here's my code:

```
public static String[]getSerializedClusterMap(){
    Cluster cluster=HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("TestCluster", "localhost:9160");
 //   Keyspace keyspace=HFactory.createKeyspace("KMeans", cluster);

    KeyspaceDefinition keyspaceDefinition=cluster.describeKeyspace("myKeyspace");

    if (cluster.describeKeyspace("myKeyspace")==null){
        ColumnFamilyDefinition columnFamilyDefinition=HFactory.createColumnFamilyDefinition("myKeyspace","clusters",ComparatorType.BYTESTYPE);
        KeyspaceDefinition keyspaceDefinition1=HFactory.createKeyspaceDefinition("myKeyspace",ThriftKsDef.DEF_STRATEGY_CLASS,1,Arrays.asList(columnFamilyDefinition));
        cluster.addKeyspace(keyspaceDefinition1,true);

    }

    Keyspace keyspace=HFactory.createKeyspace("myKeyspace", cluster);

    Mutator<String>mutator=HFactory.createMutator(keyspace, me.prettyprint.cassandra.serializers.StringSerializer.get());
    String[]serializedMap=new String[2],clusters={"cluster-0","cluster-1"};
    try{
        me.prettyprint.hector.api.query.ColumnQuery<String,String,String> columnQuery=HFactory.createStringColumnQuery(keyspace);
        for(int i=0;i<clusters.length;i++){
            columnQuery.setColumnFamily("user").setKey("cluster").setName(clusters[i]);
            QueryResult<HColumn<String,String>>result=columnQuery.execute();
            serializedMap[i]=result.get().getValue();
        }
    }catch (HectorException ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return serializedMap;
}
```

Any suggestions on to what should i do or on what the value of the replication factor should be?

After running,'use keyspace "myKeyspace;' and 'describe;',the output is:

```
    Keyspace: myKeyspace:
  Replication Strategy: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy
  Durable Writes: true
    Options: [replication_factor:3]
  Column Families:
    ColumnFamily: user
      Key Validation Class: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BytesType
      Default column value validator: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BytesType
      Cells sorted by: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BytesType
      GC grace seconds: 864000
      Compaction min/max thresholds: 4/32
      Read repair chance: 1.0
      DC Local Read repair chance: 0.0
      Populate IO Cache on flush: false
      Replicate on write: true
      Caching: KEYS_ONLY
      Bloom Filter FP chance: default
      Built indexes: []
      Compaction Strategy: org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy
      Compression Options:
        sstable_compression: org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.SnappyCompressor
```

Comment: can you run cqlsh and include output of `describe keyspace "myKeyspace"`.  Also if this is a new application I would highly recommend using cql over thrift

Comment: i posted the results of the output above

Answer (score 1):

your keyspace is configured with a RF of 3

> Options: [replication_factor:3]

On a 1 node cluster, no quorum can ever be achieved since it requires at least 2. Alter your rf to 1 or use a consistency level of ONE.